# Need a formula for Leap Year

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula in which, if the date is equal to or greater than 03/01/2015 and less than or equal to 02/29/2016 then I get the result as "Leap Year" or "No Leap Year".

Thanks!
Sumeet

Comment: Could help: [Method to determine whether a year is a leap year](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214019)

Comment: @Sumeet - What have you tried?

Comment: 2015 is not a leap year. 2016 is a leap year.

Comment: So specifically, you don't care about dates outside that very, very narrow range?

Comment: I need a formula in which there were 2 dates. First one is Term Start Date and second is Term End Date. Now, if I enter 03/01/2015 in Term Start Date and End Date would be anything then the answer would be "Leap Year" as if the Term Start Date is 3/1/2015 then financial end date would be 02/29/2016, so the answer should be "leap year" but if the Term Start Date is after 03/01/2016 then it won't consider as a Leap Year as 02/29/16 is before that date.

Comment: Why would the formula need both dates? If you knew when a term started you could work out when it ended, or vice versa. This should be doable with only one date input, as per two of the answers given below.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is that the date function in Excel will increment the month if the day is out of range so `=date(2015,1,32)`(32nd of January) returns Feb 1, 2015.

So if you have a year in A1 this formula will return if it is a leap year or not.

```
=IF(DATE(A1,2,29)=DATE(A1,3,1),"No Leap Year","Leap Year")
```

If it is not a leap year the program rounds February 29 to March 1 and is equal (no leap year).

Edit based on your comment:
If your date is in A1 and you want to find if there is a Feb 29th within the next year

```
=if((date(year(A1)+1,month(A1),day(A1))-A1)=366,"Leap Year","No Leap Year")
```

Increment the year by 1, subtract the original and check if there are 366 days.

Comment: That's a clever solution!

Comment: You could also adapt the latter formula to just compare the day number of two dates 366 days apart, if they are the same there's a leap year in between, i.e. `=IF(DAY(A1-1)=DAY(A1+365),"Leap Year","No Leap Year")`

Comment: Thank you all for this formula. That's the formula I want to use in my work. Thanks Again.

Comment: If you are happy with the formula, please accept it so people can see it is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Some people use:

> IF( date(year(A1), 2, 29) <> date(year(A1), 3, 1)  ,"Leap", "No leap")

But I don't like using invalid dates in my formula, so I use this one:

> IF( month( date(year(A1), 2, 28)+1 )=2 ,"Leap", "No leap")

Or you can count the number of days in the year (or in February) like so:

> IF( date(year(A1) + 1, 1, 1) - date(year(A1), 1, 1) = 366  ,"Leap", "No leap")

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to calculate the days between two dates: 
https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38

Calculate between 1st January and 31st December. If it equals 366, then it's a leap year.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Leap years happen every 4 years, on the fourth year.

Therefore the simplest solution is:

`=IF(MOD(YEAR(A1),4)=0,"Leap Year","No Leap Year")`

Identify the year, divide it by four (`MOD` function), and if remainder is zero then it's a leap year.

EDIT:

Sorry, for your specific problem I see you need it to return your chosen value during the first two months of a leap year, or else during the last ten months of the year before a leap year... Therefore you would need the formula to be:

```
=IF(MONTH(A1)<3,
  IF(MOD(YEAR(A1),4)=0,"Leap Year","No Leap Year"),
  IF(MOD(YEAR(A1),4)=3,"Leap Year","No Leap Year"))
```

Comment: Strictly speaking leap years won't always occur every 4 years, 2100 is not a leap year

Comment: If I live for another eighty-five years, I'll make sure to come back and update the formula, @barryhoudini... otherwise it's all yours!

Comment: As a response to "this statement is not true" I don't find "but it's mostly true!" all that compelling

Comment: How about 'it will be true every year of our lives'? If it will practically give you the correct result for 100% of the use cases you require it for, it's a correct answer. Pragmatism over fixing non-problems.